# Add Enum to a list in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, list, enums

This seems straight forward and it should! however I am struggling to add enum to a list of treatments. (I've already seen the previous similar posts, I did try the add ( EnumType.option). Not doing the job tho.

```
Public DiseaseTreatment() As TreatmentsetDiseaseTreatment

Public Enum TreatmentsetDiseaseTreatment
'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("01")>  _
Item01

''<remarks/>
 Antibiotics
''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("02")>  _
Item02

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("Pain Killers)")>  _
PainKillers




Dim temptreatment As List(Of TreatmentsetDiseaseTreatment)= New List(Of 
 TreatmentsetDiseaseTreatment)()
temptreatment.add(TreatmentsetDiseaseTreatment.Antibiotics)
temptreatment.add(TreatmentsetDiseaseTreatment.PainKillers)
```

Here is where I am getting Error: Value of Type List of (TreatmentsetDiseaseTreatment) Can not be converted to (TreatmentsetDiseaseTreatment())

```
 patient.treatmentType = temptreatment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's an array not a list, use `temptreatment.ToArray()`

```
patient.treatmentType = temptreatment.ToArray()
```

Comment: yeah, your right, not sure how I manged to do such a mistake! Thank you! :)